# Bootstrap Media Component Columizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that utilizes the media component for the Bootstrap framework. The page lists a group of CDs that are available to purchase for a private musician. What I"m trying to do is when the list reaches more than 4 songs for a given cd then it will make new column of those songs. Can someone explain to me how I can do that?

Does anyone know what I mean?

Thoughts on this anybody?

```
<div class="media">
    <span class="media-left">
        <img class="media-object" src="assets/images/cds/cd1.png" alt="CD cover for first CD.">
    </span>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="media-heading">Name of CD</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
        </ol>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <span class="media-left">
        <img class="media-object" src="assets/images/cds/cd2.png" alt="CD cover for second CD.">
    </span>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="media-heading">Name of CD</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
            <li>Song<span>Composer</span></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the css multicoloumns-solution

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

As you can see, the browser-support doesn't look good.

You could write a little js-code to ask for each `ol` the quantity (`length`) of your li's and add a Class to that list

Comment: So you feel as if this is my best solution? Or do you think I should do something different with the layout.

Comment: I think you should try to work this out with jQuery! But i'd like to know is there a cms behind that? Feel free to contact me, so we don't have to spam the commentsection :)

Comment: I don't see your email address anywhere.